# How to know what is the optimal number of clusters -- is there a way to evaluate how many clusters should actually be there?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have only started learning clustering and came across terms such as `groundtruth` which is another name for a reference known set which contains the actual clustered data into the correct groups. For educational purpose, I have created a randomly generated data set and want to cluster it to 7 clusters. Assuming that the actual clusters should be 5, how can I use this information to evaluate how good the clustering is done. Can somebody please help?

```
K=3;

numObservarations = 100;
dimensions = 3;
data = rand([numObservarations dimensions]);

numObservarations = length(data);
%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
    'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);
%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
```

Comment: You should generate your test data as a series of 5 clusters, by generating 5 groups of random coordinates with different means. Then you have a ground truth. You then cluster and evaluate how well the clusters match those of the ground truth. Error measures abound, look for Dice coefficient, F score, etc.

Comment: The random data you generate has no intrinsic clusters, any random clustering will be as good as the next.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thank you for your comment. Could you please put that as an answer since it is quite hard for me to follow because I just started learning this subject and don't understand how I can create a fake ground truth and evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to generate a test set:

```
K = 3;
numObservations = 100;
dimensions = 3;
data = cell(K,1);
for ii=1:K
   data{ii} = randn([numObservations,dimensions]) + 3 * randn([1,dimensions]);
end
data = cat(1,data{:});
labels = repmat(1:K,numObservations,1);
labels = labels(:); % This is the ground truth
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, labels, 'filled')
```

`data` is a data set, similar to the one you made, but it has three clusters in it with different means. I used `3*randn` to generate random means that sufficiently separates the clusters so that clustering has some chance of doing something right. `10*randn` will make a trivial problem, `1*randn` will make an impossible problem.

`labels` is the cluster ID that each data point belongs to. This is your "ground truth".

Next, apply k-means to the data set `data` as you did before, to obtain your `clustIDX`. Now you can compare `clustIDX` to `labels`. Because k-means assigns a random ID to each cluster (it cannot know which IDs you assigned to each cluster), don't expect the clustering to give the same IDs as your ground truth. It is possible that a correctly assigned data point has `label=2` and `clustIDX=3`. But the confusion matrix, as explained by Tommaso in the other answer, can show you how well the clustering went. It is computed as follows:

```
C = zeros(K,K);
for ii=1:length(labels)
   C(labels(ii),clustIDX(ii)) = C(labels(ii),clustIDX(ii)) + 1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to follow the code -- can you please explain the line `3*randn()` --- is 3 the variance of the signal generated using `randn()`?

Comment: Yes. The result of that is the mean for one cluster. Of course you can fix cluster means, not make them random. And you can vary cluster sizes by changing the variance/covariant within each cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and the answer. I have one more last thing to ask, could you please clarify?Is there any reason why you selected the values of the variancs as 3  and why not 0.01 or some other value? So, is 3 considered to be a larger value and hence is there a rule of thumb of selecting the variance/ covariance?

Comment: I just picked a value that made the distance between clusters large enough (w.r.t. the cluster size) so that the problem is solvable. If you use 0.01 (do it, plot the result) you'll see that the clusters overlap completely, there is nothing there for a clustering algorithm to work with, any random clustering will be as good as the next.

Comment: Sorry to sound nosy, but Matlab throws error in the line `data{ii} = randn([numObservations,dimensions]) + 3 * randn([1,dimensions]);` which is `Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.` What is the reason and how to remove it?

Comment: You probably have an older version of MATLAB. You'll have to use `bsxfun(@plus,A,B)` instead, with A and B the two matrices on either side of the + in that statement.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, one of the most common metrics to measure how good the clustering is compared to the known classes is `purity`.

The `purity` is an external evaluation criterion of clusters quality and represents the percentage of data points that were correctly classified, with a score ranging from `0` to `1`. In order to compute the `purity`, each cluster is assigned to the most frequent class in the cluster, and then the accuracy of this assignment is measured by counting the number of correctly assigned elements and dividing it by the total number of data points.

The first step for performing the calculation is creating a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). This can be achieved by looping through each cluster `CR` and counting how many objects were classified as each class `CS`:

```
     | CS_1 | CS_2 | CS_3 |
---------------------------
CR_1 |    4 |   28  |  10 |
CR_2 |   11 |    3  |  22 |
CR_3 |    8 |   14  |   0 |
CR_4 |    1 |    9  |   3 | 
CR_5 |    1 |    8  |   0 |
```

The second step consists in iterating through each cluster `CR` in order to find the maximum row value:

```
CR_1 - 28
CR_2 - 22
CR_3 - 14
CR_4 - 9
CR_5 - 8
```

In the final step, the row maximums must be aggregated and the result must be divided by the total number of data points:

```
PURITY = (28 + 22 + 14 + 9 + 8) / 122 ~= 0,66
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions, could you please clarify?(1) In my Question, how can I create the actual known classes? Can you please show an example code snippet with a toy example how to create the actual known/  ground truth? (2) Is higher value of purity better -- closer to 1 is better? Is puritymetric the same as `silhoutte()` which is  mentioned in Matlab's implementation (I just read about it now)